# Go programs won't run after MacOS Catalina upgrade

Tags: macos, go, macos-catalina

This might be a weird question, but some programs written in Go won't run on my MacBook Pro after MacOS Catalina upgrade.

However a basic "Hello World" program runs, but then I am using the writing a program using `net/http` package I get the following  error:

> Note: The programs are correct, they run fine inside a Docker container

Output (*IntelliJ*):

```
# runtime/cgo
In file included from gcc_darwin_amd64.c:6:
/usr/local/include/pthread.h:331:6: error: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Werror,-Wexpansion-to-defined]
/usr/local/include/pthread.h:200:2: note: expanded from macro '_PTHREAD_SWIFT_IMPORTER_NULLABILITY_COMPAT'
/usr/local/include/pthread.h:331:6: error: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Werror,-Wexpansion-to-defined]
/usr/local/include/pthread.h:200:34: note: expanded from macro '_PTHREAD_SWIFT_IMPORTER_NULLABILITY_COMPAT'
/usr/local/include/pthread.h:540:6: error: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Werror,-Wexpansion-to-defined]
/usr/local/include/pthread.h:200:2: note: expanded from macro '_PTHREAD_SWIFT_IMPORTER_NULLABILITY_COMPAT'
/usr/local/include/pthread.h:540:6: error: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Werror,-Wexpansion-to-defined]
/usr/local/include/pthread.h:200:34: note: expanded from macro '_PTHREAD_SWIFT_IMPORTER_NULLABILITY_COMPAT'
```

Things that I have already tried:

1. Reinstall `go`
2. Reinstall `xcode`
3. Check if `GOPATH` & `GOROOT` are properly set

Used:

```
MacOS version - Catalina 10.15.6
Go version - go1.15.2 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: seems issue with gcc reinstall gcc

Comment: tried, but no luck

Comment: Check this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38876). Must be your C compiler like mentioned above. How did you reinstall gcc? What worked for the issuer of linked issue was `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and then `xcode-select --install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, none of the tryouts worked.

I have been using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for sometime now.. so I tried to setup Go SDK, GOROOT and GOPATH using the IDE (just a thought came to my mind).

I uninstalled/deleted everything related to Go on my MacBook.

Then I installed the Go plugin on IntelliJ IDEA and as expected it prompted that Go SDK is not available, neither GOROOT and GOPATH are set.

I followed the instructions and IntelliJ IDEA took care of the rest!

It downloaded and installed Go SDK, asked me to select GOPATH, it indexed stuff and now every thing is working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Type `xcode-select -print-path` in terminal window and check your installed directory. In my case the output was: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

If it's the same case then using the following command on your terminal can fix things:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Another option is to use CGO_CPPFLAGS as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38876#issuecomment-669338355), but it would work within the session:

```
export CGO_CPPFLAGS="-Wno-error -Wno-nullability-completeness -Wno-expansion-to-defined -Wno-builtin-requires-header"
```

Comment: Mine was already set to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the `<pthread.h>` that ships with macOS tools:

This macro is even bogus for more than one reason! The definition in `<pthread.h>` is this:

```
#define _PTHREAD_SWIFT_IMPORTER_NULLABILITY_COMPAT \
    defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA) && (!defined(SWIFT_SDK_OVERLAY_PTHREAD_EPOCH) || (SWIFT_SDK_OVERLAY_PTHREAD_EPOCH < 1))
```

The macro expansion is not properly parenthesized. The macro is used this way in the same file:

```
#if !_PTHREAD_SWIFT_IMPORTER_NULLABILITY_COMPAT
```

Which expands to:

```
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA) && (!defined(SWIFT_SDK_OVERLAY_PTHREAD_EPOCH) || (SWIFT_SDK_OVERLAY_PTHREAD_EPOCH < 1))
```

The `!` only applies to the first test `defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA)` not to the whole boolean expression.

The compiler does not detect this problem, it just complains about the `defined` preprocessor operator coming from a macro expansion, which has undefined behavior as specified in the C Standard:

> **6.10.1 Conditional inclusion**
>
> [...]
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an integer constant expression except that: identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are interpreted as described below; and it may contain unary operator expressions of the form
>
> `defined identifier`
>
> or
>
> `defined ( identifier )`
>
> which evaluate to `1` if the identifier is currently defined as a macro name (that is, if it is predefined or if it has been the subject of a `#define` preprocessing directive without an intervening `#undef` directive with the same subject identifier), `0` if it is not.
>
> 2 Each preprocessing token that remains (in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling expression) after all macro replacements have occurred shall be in the lexical form of a token (6.4).
>
> **Semantics**
>
> 3 Preprocessing directives of the forms
>
> `#` `if` constant-expression new-line groupopt
>
> `#` `elif` constant-expression new-line groupopt
>
> check whether the controlling constant expression evaluates to nonzero.
>
> 4 Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the defined unary operator), just as in normal text. If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined. After all replacements due to macro expansion and the `defined` unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number `0`, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens compose the controlling constant expression which is evaluated according to the rules of 6.6. For the purposes of this token conversion and evaluation, all signed integer types and all unsigned integer types act as if they have the same representation as, respectively, the types `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` defined in the header `<stdint.h>`. This includes interpreting character constants, which may involve converting escape sequences into execution character set members. Whether the numeric value for these character constants matches the value obtained when an identical character constant occurs in an expression (other than within a `#if` or `#elif` directive) is implementation-defined. Also, whether a single-character character constant may have a negative value is implementation-defined.

This relevant phrase is *If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined.*

It is unclear if *generated* just means produced as part of the macro expansion or more specifically produced by token pasting. **clang** seems to consider that any `defined` token produced coming from a macro expansion has undefined behavior in a `#if` controlling expression.

For both reasons, this seems to be a bug in `<pthread.h>` for Apple to fix.