# Is it required and/or preferred to wrap C enum items in parenthesis , and if so, what's the utility?

Tags: c, enums, typedef, bitwise-operators, parentheses

Which one is to use?

```
typedef enum
{
  item_1  = 1,
  item_2  = 5,
  item_2  = 8,
  item_2  = 10,
} formA_typeDef;
```

or

```
typedef enum
{
  item_1  = (1),
  item_2  = (5),
  item_2  = (8),
  item_2  = (10),
} formB_typeDef;
```

I personally think that the first,  `A_typeDef;` is the adequate format to use, unless the value to assign to the item isn't a simple integer, but a combination of `#define` such as:

```
#define REG1 0xFFF7U
#define REG2 0xFFFFU

typedef enum
{
  item_1  = (REG1 | REG2 | 0x00U),
  item_2  = (REG1 | REG2 | 0x01U),
  item_2  = (REG1 | REG2 | 0x02U),
  item_2  = (REG1 | REG2 | 0x03U),
} formC_typeDef;
```

Comment: Both are equivalent. And even for something like `REG1 | REG2 | 0x00` you don't need the parentheses.

Comment: Outer parentheses like `(1)` or even `((REG1 | FOO) + 2)` are totally usless here. `1` and `(REG1 | FOO) + 2` are perfectly fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
If so, what is preferred in Embedded C? Like what's the best practice? Thanks!

Comment: @GhaziXG It's preferred not to use enums in the first place. I posted an answer.

Comment: There's no right or wrong answers, it's only a matter of personal style.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to use redundant parentheses around the initializer expression for an `enum` constant.  The first definition is fine and readable.

Conversely, if you were to define the constants as macros, you would make sure so use parentheses to avoid precedence errors when the macro is replaced with its expansion in the final expressions.

Using enums (no parentheses needed):

```
#define REG1 0x00F8U
#define REG2 0xFF00U

typedef enum {
    ITEM_1  = REG1 | REG2 | 0x00U,
    ITEM_2  = REG1 | REG2 | 0x01U,
    ITEM_3  = REG1 | REG2 | 0x02U,
    ITEM_4  = REG1 | REG2 | 0x03U,
} formC_typeDef;
```

Using macros (parentheses required):

```
#define ITEM_1  (REG1 | REG2 | 0x00U)
#define ITEM_2  (REG1 | REG2 | 0x01U)
#define ITEM_3  (REG1 | REG2 | 0x02U)
#define ITEM_4  (REG1 | REG2 | 0x03U)
```

Comment: Actually, in the case of ``#define REG2`` you might actually want to place brackets round the usage of ``(REG2)``. where REG2 is actually defined as an operation which unfortunately uses operations of lower precedence and the brackets have been forgotten -  the language does not mandate the use of brackets in macros - and causes the outer expression to be interpreted differently. In this case the only useful operation would be ``?:`` :  ``#define REG2 COND2 ? 0x1200 : 0xFF00`` would have the surprising effect of always applying 0xFF00, effectively  ignoring REG1 and the last argument.

Comment: Of course, the given values for REG1 and REG2 are nonsense... REG2 and the last argument would have no effect.

Comment: @GemTaylor: yes the values of `REG1` and `REG2` in the question are inconsistent with expressions used in the `enum` definition. I changed them in my answer for clarity.

Comment: @GemTaylor: the language does not mandate the use of brackets in macro definitions, and in some cases brackets are purposely not used, but in these definitions, mandating the use of `(ITEM_1)` would not be the correct fix for the missing brackets. Allowing unsuspecting programmers to use values defined as macros as if they were variables is common sense. In this instance, there is no side effect on macro arguments, so no further precaution is needed. Beginners need simple rules: using macros should be discouraged and mandating brackets around macro arguments and the whole expansion is better.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it required

No.

> Is it preferred

No.

> Which one is to use?

The former, because there exist no sensible arguments to use the latter version.

---

As a side note, using `enum` to store bit masks is a horrible idea since enumeration variables could get any signedness, and enumeration constants (`item_1`) are guaranteed to be signed. And you *don't* want bit masks to have a signed type, as that could lead to subtle bugs elsewhere.

And that would be the same reason as why we should always end hex constants with `u`/`U`: `#define REG1 0xFFF7u`

Comment: Thanks for the side note as well, and if I've gotten the right vision, such case of the pseudo-code here above, is okay, since both REG1 and REG2 are defined as Unsigned  (hex value ending with U) ?

Answer (score 1):

The convention of putting brackets round everything is very much a defence against badly written macros. Stop using macros, and you stop having to be so defensive.

In the case of `#define REG2` you might actually want to place brackets round the usage of `(REG2)` where REG2 is actually defined as an operation which unfortunately uses operations of lower precedence and the brackets have been forgotten -  the language does not mandate the use of brackets in macros - and causes the outer expression to be interpreted differently. Of course a house rule that mandates all macro definitions are bracketed also helps.

In your case the only useful operation would be `?:`, as all other operations are higher precedence than `|`

Imagine if  `#define REG2 COND2 ? 0x1200 : 0xFF00`

Without any brackets, `REG1 | REG2 | 0x02U` would be interpreted as:

```
REG1 | COND2 ? 0x1200U : 0xFF00U | 0x02U
```

Which is actually

```
(REG1 | COND2) ? 0x1200U : (0xFF00U | 0x02U)
```

This would have the surprising effect of almost always applying 0x1200, effectively  ignoring COND2 and the last argument.

To ensure you always get the correct behaviour, you would want to bracket the REG2 clause, indeed, do both possible macros to get completely safe behaviour:

```
(REG1) | (REG2) | 0x02U
```

That said, the use of brackets round the whole expression is completely redundant, at least in this case, where we "all know" that assignment has pretty much lowest priority.

By choosing `|` in your example it makes it quite difficult to generate a realistic example. A more realistic one is when ANDing with a mask:

```
#define MASK1 0x00F0U|0x000F

unsigned v = 0x1234U & MASK1;
```

Is expanded as

```
unsigned v = 0x1234U & 0x00F0U|0x000F;
```

But by precedence rules, becomes:

```
unsigned v = (0x1234 & 0x00F0U) | 0x000F;
```

For the surprising answer `0x003F`

So, as a belts-and-braces rule, every "value" macro you **define** should have surrounding brackets, and every **usage** of a macro you don't trust/know should be bracketed. The following will never be misinterpreted, but does look ugly:

```
#define MASK1 (0x00F0U|0x000F)

unsigned v = 0x1234U & (MASK1);
```

Also, don't ignore the compiler warnings when the compiler thinks you don't know the precedence rules, but they won't always save you.

If you have absolute confidence that the first rule was followed, or you have an IDE that lets you see the definitions, then maybe you don't need to be so careful when using macro values. Of course, someone could come along in the future and change a definition into an unsafe one, but that should be spotted in code review. You might upgrade an external library header. So how trusting are you?

Alternatively, stop using macros, which probably means start using C++11 typed enums instead.

Comment: Not trusting macros is indeed good advice. Here is a pathological example in a standard header file on macOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72164827/4593267

Comment: Hmm... really wanted to make the point incase the OP just misunderstood the problem. I have added a couple of clarifiers.